# How secure is OpenVPN on a public server

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

If I use a VPN Connection on a server that many others use as well for their VPNs, is there any chance they could sniff my traffic or see my packets as we are on the same local network?

If so, how do you protect against that?

Comment: "is there any chance they could sniff my traffic or see my packets as we are on the same local network" -> Yes. It's a very small chance, but it's non-zero for sure. To clarify, 100% they'll be able to see your packets. They won't be able to see their contents without some MITM attack, though. Security greatly depends on implementation and usage. Of course, anyone with root access to that server can get access to *everything*.

Comment: The other VPN users shouldn't ever see any of your packets, but like EEAA says, the box owner can see/capture anything they want, if they want to.

Answer (score -1):

the server owner could capture your traffic and analysis them.
although your encrypted connections (using protocols like https(use ssl/tls),ssh,other vpns) will remain secure.

Comment: No!  This... just demonstrates a horrible lack of understand of security and cryptology.